# Graphical support when running R as another user

Tags: r, ubuntu

I'm running R as another user on my system (sudo -uTest R), and certain commands (e.g. plot) fail with 'unable to open connection to X11 display'. This works fine running R normally, so I know it has to do with running as someone else. I'm guessing this happens because Test doesn't have the desktop/display/whatever running under their name so there's nowhere to draw the graph.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a terminal window, type:

```
 xauth merge /path-to-your-home-directory/.Xauthority
```